Python - Dataset anonimization script by grouping variables
TL;DR: How can I code an aggregation, in python, to guarantee is impossible to identify an individual, retaining as much data as possible, and avoiding groups too large?
Example
Imagine a dataset of Foobar observations as show bellow:



Observation
Species
Color
Food
PK




1
bar
red
meat
bar;red;meat


2
bar
blue
meat
bar;blue;meat


3
foo
blue
meat
foo;blue;meat


4
foo
blue
meat
foo;blue;meat


5
qux
red
egg
qux;red;egg


6
foo
blue
egg
foo;blue;egg


7
bar
yellow
egg
bar;yellow;egg


8
qux
red
egg
qux;red;egg


9
baz
red
egg
baz;red;egg


10
bar
red
meat
bar;red;meat



Due to legal restrictions no Foobar that participates the experiment can be identify. Is possible to check this counting the PK observations.



PK
Count of Observation




bar;blue;meat
1


foo;blue;meat
2


qux;red;egg
2


foo;blue;egg
1


bar;yellow;egg
1


baz;red;egg
1


bar;red;meat
2


Total
10



As we can see, there is 4 Foobar that can be identify by they characteristics.
Manually this can be done:

So the occurrences became:



PK
Count of Observation




bar∪baz;red∪yellow;egg
2


qux;red;egg
2


foo;blue;egg∪meat
3


bar;blue∪red;meat
3


Total
10



But the dataset is too large to make this by hand.
My inicial solution was to iterate over all variables and count then, the inretate of all combinations of variables, but my dataset has more than 50 variables. This way the code will have (2^50 - 1) or 1.125.899.906.842.623 intarations over a a dataset that has more than 170.000 observations.
NOTE: The result does not need to be exactly the same as shown above the most important is not have a single PK observation.
